# Difference between No of rows in Select * from Table and Select count(*) from Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table in my database, when I give `Select * from Tablename`, number records showing 70079. If I give `Select count(*) from Tablename` count showing 70090. Is it cause any problem?

Comment: Data in the table has been modified by someone between your two queries. In this case, it seems like 11 rows were added, although it's also possible some were deleted and more than 11 were added.

Comment: thank you for your immediate response. but am sure, in between no one accessed this table to modify or delete the records.

Comment: Dirty read, perhaps... Are you doing anything else? Have you just inserted some records in a transaction, but not committed yet?

Comment: How are you sure? Did you start a transaction and take an exclusive lock on the table before running your queries? Is your database on your un-networked local machine, and there are no other processes running that can access the DB? Try this: `begin tran; select * from Tablename with (tablockx); select count(*) from Table Name; commit;`